# Blender 2.8 Viewport not working

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I recently downloaded Blender 2.8 beta from blender.org. 
It opens very well, but I can´s use it.

I can´t rotate the viewport or select objects shown in it. It is not reacting at all. 
Other buttons like for example changing from object into edit mode or navigate through the properties panel work.

I tried to download it again, but it didn´t help.
So my brother tried the completely same version on his computer, and strangely it worked perfectly.

I have also Blender 2.79 installed, which also works without problems.

My PC: 
Lenovo Ideapad Y70017ISK , Windows 10 64 bit, Intel Core i7, Nvidia GeForce GTX960M (Game Ready Driver 419.67)

Blender Version:

2.8 Beta, Date 28.03.2019, Hash d5cb425b8745

When I look into the system console in Blender after starting it, following lines appear:

```
Read prefs: C:\Users\Dominik\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\addons\node_wrangler.py", line 49, in <module>
    from glob import glob
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\glob.py", line 4, in <module>
    import re
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
AssertionError: SRE module mismatch

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\__init__.py", line 78, in main
    utils.load_scripts()
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 275, in load_scripts
    _initialize()
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 47, in _initialize
    enable(addon.module)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 359, in enable
    handle_error(ex)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 299, in handle_error
    import traceback
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
AssertionError: SRE module mismatch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 188, in register_module_call
    register()
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\startup\bl_operators\__init__.py", line 70, in register
    register_class(cls)
ValueError: register_class(...): already registered as a subclass

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\__init__.py", line 78, in main
    utils.load_scripts()
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 263, in load_scripts
    test_register(mod)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 230, in test_register
    register_module_call(mod)
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\blender-2.80-d5cb425b8745-win64\blender-2.80.0-git.d5cb425b8745-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 190, in register_module_call
    import traceback
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.79\python\lib\sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
AssertionError: SRE module mismatch

location: <unknown location>:-1

location: <unknown location>:-1
Keymap: '3D View Tool: Select Box' not found for tool 'builtin.select_box'
Keymap: '3D View Tool: Select Box' not found for tool 'builtin.select_box'
Keymap: '3D View Tool: Select Box' not found for tool 'builtin.select_box'
Keymap: '3D View Tool: Select Box' not found for tool 'builtin.select_box'
```

When I position the mouse over the viewport, the Keymap... entrys at the end of the list get more and more.

Can anyone please help me getting blender work?

Comment: "Lenovo Ideapad" does not suffice as a description of your hardware. Please use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135736/edit) link at the bottom of your question (i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information about your hardware. The exact model of your laptop, the version of your graphics drivers, ...

Comment: Version of your graphics card driver is still missing.

Comment: Also, be aware that Blender 2.80 is still in Beta. It certainly would help more if you submit your hardware/bug related questions about Blender 2.80 Beta to the [official bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/project/2/type/Bug/).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution for my problem.

I had two versions of blender installed parallel on my PC; Blender 2.79 and the 2.80 beta.

When looking more precise into the system console provided by blender, I recognized that Blender 2.80 was using the python library of the 2.79 version.

To solve this issue while keeping both versions installed, I just changed the name of the 2.79´s version. So the 2.80 version couldn´t find the python library of the older version and used its own.

I don´t know if this is the right way to solve such an issue but for me it worked perfectly. Now I can use 2.80 like there would had never been problems.